# Annotate and Aggregate function in django

Tags: django-models, django-queryset, django-managers

In django I have the following tables and am trying to count the number of votes by item.

```
class Votes(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)


class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    description = models.TextField()
```

I have the following queryset

```
queryset = Votes.objects.values('item__name').annotate(Count('item'))
```

that returns a list with item name and view count but not the item object. How can I set it up so that the object is returned instead of just the string value? I have been messing around with Manager and Queryset methods, that the right track? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something this:

`queryset = Votes.values.annotate(t_count=Count('item'))`

To get the count value of first Vote object:

```
queryset[0].t_count
```

or to get Item object:

```
Item.objects.annotate(i_count=Count('votes'))
```

Comment: This returns the count of the objects but not the object itself which I can call methods on. How can I link up the actual objects that are being aggregated?

Comment: you can access object queryset[0].user or for the sencond exmaple queryset[0].name